# Android | Когда добавляю слушателя перестают меняться цвета в BottomNavigationMenu

Tags: java, android

Есть следующий код:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case id.page_1:

                            break;
                        case id.page_2:

                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Когда у меня этого код нет, то без проблем можно переключаться по пунктам меню. Вернее, я нажимаю на определенный пункт меню, то он становится соответствующего цвета. Однако, никакого функционала при этом нет. Когда Я добавляю слушателя, код которого приведен выше, чтобы реализовать функционал, то у меня перестают меняться цвета иконок меню.

Как сделать так, чтобы при добавлении слушателя цвета иконок меню тоже менялись?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена после добавления в слушатель следующего кода:

```
                        item.setChecked(true);
```